# calculating derivative of bias in backpropagation

Tags: neural-network, gradient-descent, backpropagation, gradient, derivation

Looking at the algorithm in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation#Matrix_multiplication), we can implement backpropagation by calculating:

$$\delta^{L}=\left(f^{L}\right)'\cdot\nabla_{a^{L}}C$$
(where I treat $\left(f^{L}\right)'$ as an $n\times n$ matrix and not a vector)

$$\nabla_{W^{l}}C=\delta^{l}\left(a^{l-1}\right)^{T}$$
(this is the outer product of the two vectors)

$$\delta^{l-1}=\left(f^{l-1}\right)'\cdot\left(W^{l}\right)^{T}\cdot\delta^{l}$$

but the one thing that isn't clear to me is what should the derivative with respect to the bias be: $\nabla_{b^{l}}C$.

Comment: bias usually is part of the weight matrix

Comment: @NikosM. but taking the derivative still does not look that trivial, and the dimensions don't seem fitting